# Hybrid Mobile App Event tracking or analytics

Tags: mobile, google-analytics, angular, event-tracking, mobile-analytics

I am developing an app built using Angular 2, so I'm constrained to platforms with Cordova plugins (that are available for Cordova Build) or JavaScript Web SDKs.

I have a few simple technical requirements

Track navigation of user or application flow (page views - user navigated to profile page)

Track custom events (user hit cancel when prompted to enter credit card)

Track custom user properties (dimensions - eg. Gender, Location, Age Range)

I'm Considering 
Google Analytics - However i see it throws a lot metrics and numbers, but not what I need. I want details of an individual user or a individual application flow and how the user used his application, what was the flow etc, With respect to each device.

Any advice on a platform or SDK I can use to actually retrieve these important analytics which is device or user specific would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do individual level event tracking with different plugins like Appsee and UXCam.

Appsee and UXCam also provides additional support of Video recording of the app and user interactions done by the user i.e, how the user used the application etc. In Addition to that Appsee also provides crash log and analytic support.

Links for Appsee - https://www.appsee.com and 
UXCam - https://uxcam.com

Comment: Why do you use both? Do they have complementary features? Do you use Google analytics as well?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/angulartics/angulartics2
angulartics has been rewritten to support angular 2. it supports google analytics. It should work in your angular 2 application. let me know if it works. I would like to play with it as well. There is a angularitics cordova plugin but it is not updated for angular2 yet.